# Python - Count occurrences of certain ranges in a list

Tags: python, list, count, range, histogram

So basically I want to count the number of occurrences a floating point appears in a given list.  For example: a list of grades (all scores out of 100) are inputted by the user and they are sorted in groups of ten.  How many times do scores from 0-10, 10-20, 20-30.. etc) appear?  Like test score distribution.  I know I can use the count function but since I'm not looking for specific numbers I'm having trouble.  Is there a away to combine the count and range?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9):

To group the data, divide it by the interval width.  To count the number in each group, consider using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  Here's a worked out example with documentation and a test:

```
from collections import Counter

def histogram(iterable, low, high, bins):
    '''Count elements from the iterable into evenly spaced bins

        >>> scores = [82, 85, 90, 91, 70, 87, 45]
        >>> histogram(scores, 0, 100, 10)
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2]

    '''
    step = (high - low + 0.0) / bins
    dist = Counter((float(x) - low) // step for x in iterable)
    return [dist[b] for b in range(bins)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I looks like you downvoted all four answers that were written before yours. If that's the case, then I'd say that, despite your answer might be the best one, maybe not all the other ones deserve the downvote because they might be useful after all (even if none of them is the best one).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm trying to implement your solution and I'm running into problems with the mathematical operators.  For example, the step and dist variables wont work on strings.  Sorry if I sound like a total noob (it's because I am) but is there a way to force the scores into a list?  What I'm inputting is 11,48,13,9,4.  Is that a string by default?

Comment: Sorry about the multiple comments. Here's what I'm working with: 'from collections import Counter 
def gradeDistribution(examScores, low, high, bins):
   step = (high - int(low) + 0.0) / bins 
   dist = Counter((x - int(low)) // step for x in examScores) 
   return [dist[b] for b in range(bins)] 
examScores=[raw_input("please enter scores")]
 
gradeDistribution(examScores, 0, 100, 10)'
 
The error message I'm getting is : 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' Thanks for any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: @user1246457 When this happens you should update your question, you can leave a short comment if you want the to make sure someone specific is notified of the update. That way you don't hit the comment limit and your code can be readable. When the user enters the scores, they're stored as strings. you should convert them to floats or ints before calling the histogram function by doing something like `[float(i) for i in examScores]`.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the *float* conversion from the string input.

Answer (score 7):

If you are fine with using the external library NumPy, then you just need to call `numpy.histogram()`:

```
>>> data = [82, 85, 90, 91, 70, 87, 45]
>>> counts, bins = numpy.histogram(data, bins=10, range=(0, 100))
>>> counts
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2])
>>> bins
array([   0.,   10.,   20.,   30.,   40.,   50.,   60.,   70.,   80.,
         90.,  100.])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
decs = [int(x/10) for x in scores]
```

maps scores from 0-9 -> 0, 10-19 -> 1, et cetera. Then just count the occurrences of 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on (via something like `collections.Counter`), and map back to ranges from there.

Comment: There's technically a difference - `x//10` will generate a `float` result, whereas `int(x/10)` will generate an `int`.

Comment: Sure, @RaymondHettinger - but I didn't say anything about `list.count`, so I'm not sure why you're mentioning that.

Comment: Ya they are different but I think `//` is pretty awesome so I bring it up any time I can.

Answer (score 2):

This method uses bisect which can be more efficient, but it requires that you sort the scores first.

```
from bisect import bisect
import random

scores = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in xrange(100)]
bins = [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]

scores.sort()
counts = []
last = 0
for range_max in bins:
    i = bisect(scores, range_max, last)
    counts.append(i - last)
    last = i
```

I wouldn't expect you to install numpy just for this, but if you already have numpy you can use `numpy.histogram`.

UPDATE

First, using bisect is more flexible. Using `[i//n for i in scores]` requires that all the bins are the same size. Using bisect allows the bins to have arbitrary limits. Also `i//n` means the ranges are [lo, hi). Using bisect the ranges are (lo, hi] but you can use bisect_left if you want [lo, hi).

Second bisect is faster, see timings bellow. I've replaced scores.sort() with the slower sorted(scores) because the sorting is the slowest step and I didn't want to bias the times with a pre-sorted array, but the OP says his/her array is already sorted so bisect could make even more sense in that case.

```
setup="""
from bisect import bisect_left
import random
from collections import Counter

def histogram(iterable, low, high, bins):
    step = (high - low) / bins
    dist = Counter(((x - low + 0.) // step for x in iterable))
    return [dist[b] for b in xrange(bins)]

def histogram_bisect(scores, groups):
    scores = sorted(scores)
    counts = []
    last = 0
    for range_max in groups:
        i = bisect_left(scores, range_max, last)
        counts.append(i - last)
        last = i
    return counts

def histogram_simple(scores, bin_size):
    scores = [i//bin_size for i in scores]
    return [scores.count(i) for i in range(max(scores)+1)]

scores = [random.randint(0,100) for _ in xrange(100)]
bins = range(10, 101, 10)
"""
from timeit import repeat
t = repeat('C = histogram(scores, 0, 100, 10)', setup=setup, number=10000)
print min(t)
#.95
t = repeat('C = histogram_bisect(scores, bins)', setup=setup, number=10000)
print min(t)
#.22
t = repeat('histogram_simple(scores, 10)', setup=setup, number=10000)
print min(t)
#.36
```

Comment: I concur with @amber.  The use of *bisect* here is a waste when you can use a simple division for evenly spaced bins.

Comment: I think @RaymondHettinger and I were thinking of a different usage of `bisect` than what you wound up doing here (namely, using bisect to find which bin an individual score goes into, which *would* be a waste). For large numbers of scores, you're right, bisect is potentially efficient.